# Return only the first three words which are separate by a comma using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a variable that contains "aaa,bbb,cccc ddd,eee". And I would like to return only the first 3 words separate by ','.

In this example, it should return  "aaa,bbb,cccc ddd".

How can I achieve this using ampscript?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far, you don't seem to have done much research, please udpate your post with a specific problem you are encountering while attempting to do so. "Questions on problems in code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. For help writing short, self-contained syntactically-valid examples, see: [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For returning first three values using Amp Script

```
%%[
VAR @Text ,@Split1, @Split2, @Split3

SET @Text = "aaa,bbb,cccc ddd,eee"

SET @Rows = BuildRowSetFromString(@Text, ",")

SET @Split1 = Field(Row(@Rows, 1), 1)

SET @Split2 = Field(Row(@Rows, 2), 1)

SET @Split3 = Field(Row(@Rows, 3), 1)
]%%

%%=v(@Split1)=%%</br>

%%=v(@Split2)=%%</br>

%%=v(@Split3 )=%%</br>
```

please refer this documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm for more information

Comment: "Try with this" is not a very reassuring answer, please elaborate on why this should work, explain your approach to the OP and link any relevant documentation. Thanks

Comment: Now that you have added a documentation link, please include the essentials from it on why the code you provided should work (or at least explain your approach), thanks for the update!

Comment: will gladly do so once you have explained and described why your code should work ;)

Comment: For reference purposes: [answer] Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.